# mysql get array of ids

Tags: mysql, database, select, count

So i have a database with a few tables. the main is Plant. I also have a PlantEffects table that has plant_id, effect_id.  What I need to do select Plants but with the top 5 PlantEffects by count on PlantEffects.effect_id. So it would come out as

```
|ID|NAME|top_effect_ids|
|1 |abc |1,4,5,6,7     |
|2 |def |3,2,9,7,5     |
```

Comment: Can you post your table schema and some sample data? This will make it much easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the top five `effect_id`s (by count) into a CSV list.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.name, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(b.effect_id ORDER BY b.effectcnt DESC), ',', 5) AS top_effect_ids
FROM 
    plants a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT plant_id, effect_id, COUNT(1) AS effectcnt
    FROM planteffects
    GROUP BY plant_id, effect_id
) b ON a.id = b.plant_id
GROUP BY 
    a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

you should normalize your table first.

mean: don't write the top_effect_ids in one column, rather create a table with a foreign key of Plant ID and the effect ID and write 5 rows (for example: `(1,1) , (1,4) , (1,5) , (1,6) , (1,7)`

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization